# Enable port 1935 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: tcp, port

I am working on **RTMP protocol** in ffmpeg. For that i have enabled RTMP in ffmpeg. But while running ffplay with rtmp url and **port 1935**, i am getting tcp connection error.
So if anyone knows solution to ***enable port 1935*** in ubuntu 18.04, please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: Search google for “ufw open port”

Comment: Thank you for your response sir.I tried with that but when i am checking for open ports in my ubuntu machine using cmd "sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN", it is not showing in that list with port 1935. But it shows in ufw status. This same method i had applied for enabling for port 443 but it didnt worked.